# I want to create a like counter in Django, but I get an error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to create a like counter for an exercise project that receives and counts the number of likes from self and displays them in templates .

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} - {self.update}'
     # Define a get_absolute_url() method to tell Django
     # how to calculate the canonical URL for an object.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home:post_detail',args=(self.pk ,self.slug))
    def likes_count(self):
        ....... #My problem is here

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,name='uvote')
    post = models.ForeignKey(post,on_delete=models.CASCADE , name='pvote')
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.uvote} ---- {self.pvote.slug}'
```

I tried this code (told to me in my tutorial)

```
    def likes_count(self):
        return self.pvote.count()
```

Comment: So exactly what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify this as [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), so the name of the relation in *reverse*:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uvote')
    post = models.ForeignKey(post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pvote')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.user}'
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `Post` instead of <s>`post`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).